# is there a way to have a package name for grails config.groovy

Tags: grails

Is there a way to have a package name for grails conf file config.groovy.
By default, this file does not have a package name. I tried to enter a package name (like com.mycom.grails.conf) but got errors. I looked around but don't find any way. Is there a way to pass parameter to run-app or set an env variable etc??

Comment: people tend to usually provide an override file that sits outside of their application context and is then editable by ops guys and so forth.. if you need instructions on this let me know..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Config.groovy` is a configuration file and can not have a package name. However, you can pass environment variables to `run-app`. The [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Command%20Line/run-app.html) demonstrates this.

```
grails run-app -DmyVariable=Something
```

Comment: What I meant was passing package name for config.groovy as run-app parameter. But anyway you gave me answer to my question with your first sentence.

Comment: Why can't it have a package name? What causes this limitation?

Comment: It's by design. Grails expect the configuration to be in the root package for your application.